# ES6 class getter, temporary return or alternative solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to solve a problem I am seeing when rendering a list of items in my ui that is coming out of a es6 class I have created. The model is working great, however I am using animations that are listening to (in react) mount, onEnter, and onLeave of the items.

When I apply my filters and sorting via the model and spit back the new list of items via the getter, the animations do not apply to some items because the list is just being re sorted, not necessarily changed.

So my getter just grabs `this.products` of the class and returns it and applies a sort order to it. And if filters are applied (which are tracked by `this._checkedList` in the class), the `this.products` is reduced based on which filters are selected then sorted. So that getter looks like so :

```
  get productList() {
    if (this._checkedList.length > 0) {
      const filteredProducts = _.reduce(this.filterMap, reduceFilters, []);
      const deDuped = _.uniq(filteredProducts, 'id');

      return this.applySort(deDuped);
    }
    const deDuped = _.uniq(this.products, 'id');

    return this.applySort(deDuped);
  }
```

What I am trying to figure out, is a way to to temporarily send back an empty array while the filters or sorting run. The reason being the ui would receive an empty array (even if for a split second) and react would register the new sorted/filtered list as a new list and fire the enter/leave/mount animations again.

My attempt was to set a local property of the class like -

```
 this._tempReturn = false;
```

then in the functions where the sort or filter happen, I set it to true, then back to false when the function is done like this -

```
    toggleFilter(args) {
      this._tempReturn = true;

      ...toggle logic

     this._tempReturn = false; 

   }
```

Then changed the getter to check for that property before i do anything else, and if it's true, send back an empty array  -

```
    get productList() {  

       if (this._tempReturn) {
        return  [];
       }
     ...
    }
```

However, this does not seem to work. Even putting a console.log in the `if (this._tempReturn) {` didn't show any logs.

I also tried sending back a new list with lodash's `_.cloneDeep` like so :

```
   get productList() {
    if (this._checkedList.length > 0) {
      const filteredProducts = _.reduce(this.filterMap, reduceFilters, []);
      const deDuped = _.uniq(filteredProducts, 'id');

      return _.cloneDeep(this.applySort(deDuped));
    }
    const deDuped = _.uniq(this.products, 'id');

    return _.cloneDeep(this.applySort(deDuped));
  }
```

this did not work either. So it seems the empty array return might be a better approach.

I am wondering if there is some way to achieve this - I would like to have the array be return empty for a second perhaps while the filters and sort are applying.

Very stuck on how to achieve, perhaps I am even looking at this problem from the wrong angle and there is a much better way to solve this. Any advice would be welcomed, thanks for reading!

Comment: You will need to render the view twice-- once with the empty array and again with the data.  That is an async component that can be implemented with events, callbacks or promises.  However, the implementation would be different depending on your React implementation.  For example, if using redux, you'd probably have two actions-- something like `GET_ARRAY_START` and `GET_ARRAY_COMPLETE` where you would load the store with an empty array on start and the actual data on complete.  Whatever method you choose you also need a way to tell React that it is time to re-render once the data is ready

Comment: You shouldn't need to render the list as empty and then as sorted in order for it to render changes properly.  It sounds like you just need to make sure your items have unique key properties.  Changing key property on a child will always make react re-render the child.

Comment: @MikeDriver That was it! I feel so silly for not checking that, I was using index as the key. If you want to add an answer I will mark as correct. Thanks!!

Comment: @ajmajmajma  Will do, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to force a re-render of items in a list when updating them you just need to make sure that each items has a unique `key` property.

Instead of rendering the list, then rendering it as empty, then re-rendering a changed list make sure each child has a unique key.  Changing the key property on a child in an array will always cause it to re-render.